# Polymorphism allocation in a SELECT TYPE construct

Tags: compiler-errors, polymorphism, fortran, allocation, fortran2003

I am trying to define a subroutine which allocates different types of arrays. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
subroutine Allocation1(Vec)
    class(*), allocatable, intent(out)      :: Vec(:)

    select type(Vec)
    type is(real(8))
        allocate(Vec(10)); Vec = 0.D0
    type is(complex(8))
        allocate(Vec(10)); Vec = (0.D0,0.D0)
    type is(integer)
        allocate(Vec(10)); Vec = 0
    endselect
endsubroutine Allocation1
```

But I got three error messages that I don't understand:

```
error #8306: Associate name defined in ASSOCIATE or SELECT TYPE statements doesn't have ALLOCATABLE or POINTER attribute   [VEC]
```

As you can see `VEC` is an allocatable array, so I don't think this error make sense.  What does it mean, and how do I make this work?

I am using IVF XE 14.0.1.139.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a compiler bug, works with Gfortran and with the Solaris Studio. I recommend you to contact your official Intel support.

As IanH points out, it is possible the other compilers are in error to compile that. Anyway, be it standard conforming or not, the procedure would still be useless, because for the select type to work the variable would still have to be already allocated, because the actual argument to your procedure must be polymorphic. You cannot just pass `real, allocatable` there.

Comment: @FortCpp But do note that your subroutine has no real sense. It is practically unusable. You have to pass an already allocated array for the `select type` to work.

Comment: @FortCpp And also note, you should probably update to intel 15.0, but the error remains the same there.

Comment: It is really nice to know this. In fact, I want to hide the information of the array size and the size is defined in the type and the subroutine will be a part of the type.

Comment: I think gfortran and solaris studio have the bug.  No mention of allocatable is made in the properties of the associate name.

Comment: This was the first I had in mind, but I didn't pursue it because the other compilers accepted it, but even more because the procedure is useless anyway.

Comment: @IanH My reading of F2008 8.1.9 is that when `selector` is a variable, `it is permitted` because the ASSOCIATE restrictions do not have an effect.

Comment: Or maybe not, I am not sure.

Comment: See 16.5.1.6p2 xxxxxx

Comment: But, 8.1.9.1p2 and the associate name is not used at all, I would ask c.l.f. for an interp.

Comment: Inside the construct, `Vec` is the associate name (if I'm looking at the bit of text you mean for me to look at) - it is as if you had `SELECT TYPE (Vec => Vec)` - and then inside the construct references to `Vec` are references to that associate name.  As per that clause 16 thing, it isn't allocatable and cannot be used in an allocate statement.  At execution time there's then the issue of the selector referencing an unallocated object.

Comment: nagfor 6.0 also refuses to compile the code in question (for what that's worth).

Answer (score 0):

A variable with intent(out) attribute is not allocated, so Vec will have no type and SELECT TYPE(VEC) is undefinable.